# How to remove door hinge cap?

Tags: doors, hinges

[image]

I have a door that swings open, I’ve watched a few videos about removing the pin and bending it to stop the swing.

Unfortunately none of the videos I’ve watched have a hinge like mine, in the photo the left hand side of the hinge forms the top and bottom caps. They seem welded together so I’ve no idea how to get the pin out.

Can anybody help? I thought maybe it wa something to do with the two holes near the caps but I’ve proded it and nothing happens

All the videos I’ve watched either have one cap or they hit the bottom cap with a nail but that’s not going to work for my hinge

Comment: I think you'd be better off fitting a door-closer than mangling a high-quality hinge like that. The mix of Philips and Pozi-Driv screws is also distressing.

Comment: And it looks like it might be a captive pin hinge - one that can't be easily removed.

Comment: Really? your sonic screw driver doesn't give you all the info you need ? Check back here in the future.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
It looks like a fixed pin hinge with security caps on both ends. If so unscrewing it from the jamb or hinge is the only way to take the door  down.

Circled in red  are two pins or screws look at both sides see if there is a way to unscrew them.  If the set pin/screw does not extend through the entire hinge or have a place for using a tool to unscrew it is a security hinge that has a non removable pin.
Your hinge is found [here](https://www.carlislebrass.com/products/hinges/ce-and-ball-bearing/enduro-grade-13-ball-bearing-hinge-grade-316-stainless-steel) on the manufacturer’s website. It is a very good ball bearing hinge that should not need any tweaking. Bending it would surely compromise the smooth operation.  The wall the door is mounted in may be a bit out of plumb causing the door to swing open. I would investigate installing a door closer on it as @RedGrittyBrick suggests.

Edit: I asked about this hinge on Amazon UK it is s fixed pin hinge not designed to be separated.